# Records and Positional Pattern matching with ".."

Tags: c#, pattern-matching

I would have expected the ".." (slice) syntax to work when using positional pattern matching, like it does with array elements.

Here is my example:

```
  // Create and populate a record
  var vehicle = new VehicleData(2, "Model Y", 99_990M, 5, 3.5M);

  // Record, deconstruct, and positional pattern matching
  var bestForCustomer = vehicle switch
  {
    (_, "Model Y", ..) => "Best for small family",            // Doesn't work
    (_, "Model X", _, _, _) => "Best for large family",       // _ does work
    (_, "Model X Plaid", _, _, _) => "Best for performance",
    _ => "Best for price"
  };
```

Anyone know why the .. (slice) syntax doesn't work in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use `..` (slice) in pattern matching but this syntax is a part of [List patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/list-patterns). It's not acceptable to use this syntax for record, only for types that has an accessible indexer that takes a `Range` as an argument or otherwise an accessible `Slice` method with two `int` parameters.

Here is a quote from a documentation for list patterns:

> A `list_pattern` is compatible with any type that is `countable` as well as `indexable` — it has an accessible indexer that takes an `Index` as an argument or otherwise an accessible indexer with a single `int` parameter. If both indexers are present, the former is preferred.
>
> A `slice_pattern` with a subpattern is compatible with any type that is `countable` as well as `sliceable` — it has an accessible indexer that takes a `Range` as an argument or otherwise an accessible `Slice` method with two `int` parameters. If both are present, the former is preferred.
>
> A `slice_pattern` without a subpattern is compatible with any type that is compatible with a `list_pattern`.

So you can use only [discard pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/discards#pattern-matching-with-switch) `_` as a placeholder for the elements that you want to ignore.

Also note that list patterns works only in C# 11 and later versions.